# Excel - calculating the median without removing duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  Total
3   3
3   3
3   3
4   11
4   11
4   11
4   11
4   11
4   11
6   9
6   9
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
7   13
```

I would like to calculate the median of column B (Total), excluding duplicate combinations of columns A and B. This could be achieved by constructing a table as below, and calculating the median from that table.

```
ID  Total
3   3
4   11
6   9
7   13
```

Is there any way of obtaining the median without having to go through this process of manually deleting duplicates?

Comment: By not going through the process manually, you mean that you don't want to go Data > Remove Duplicates after selecting both columns, right? (As opposed to manually deleting them out yourself.)

Comment: I want a formula that allows me to calculate the same median value using the original table.

Comment: Are the ID always matching the same total or can you have for example: 
{ID; Total}{
(3,   3)
(3,   11)
(3,   3)
(3,   5)}
And so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=MEDIAN(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A25&"|"&B2:B25,A2:A25&"|"&B2:B25,0),ROW(A2:A25)-MIN(ROW(A2:A25))+1),B2:B25))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way with two additional columns. The first column is concatenation of ID and Total, the second counts occurences of each individual combination. Then you just do the median on those rows where the combination occurs for the first time.

[image: solution]